# Toggle div's appearance with radio button

Tags: jquery

I had a similar issue previously, and was able to get that sorted for an either/or situation. What I want is the "yes" radio button to toggle the appearance of a div with additional questions.  After looking at other solutions in the forums, I think my HTML is solid but my jquery is wonky. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name$='yes']").click(function(){
    var test = $(this).val();

    $("div.desc").show();
});
});
```

Here's a fiddle with my html as well as jQuery :
http://jsfiddle.net/g63m9yyg/

Also, if there are any good jQuery/JS tutorials or resources, please refer me. HTML/CSS was easy for me to pick up but I'm struggling with jQuery, and I'm using it a lot for this project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have forgotten to load the jQuery library in your fiddle. Also, the input element with the name `ifmachinery` does not exist... I believe you are referring to the one with the name `machinery`?

Instead of binding the click event to inputs, I usually recommend binding it to the `.change()` event, and then use a logic to decide what to do depending on the value of the input. In this sense your code will be extensible and easily modifiable, and likely to be more verbose.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='machinery']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='yes') {
            $("div.desc").show();
        } else {
            $("div.desc").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/g63m9yyg/2/

If you want this logic to apply when the page is first loaded, you will have to run/execute this logic on DOM ready, too. Instead of repeating the function twice, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Run when DOM is ready
    if($(this).val()=='yes') {
        $("div.desc").show();
    } else {
        $(("div.desc").hide();
    }

    // When input is changed
    $("input[name='machinery']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='yes') {
            $("div.desc").show();
        } else {
            $(("div.desc").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can simply put the logic in a function, and call it with both DOM ready and input onChange events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Define logic
    var ifMachinery = function(ele) {
        if(ele.val()=='yes') {
            $("div.desc").show();
        } else {
            $("div.desc").hide();
        }   
    }

    // Run logic on DOM ready
    ifMachinery($("input[name='machinery']"));

    // Run logic when input onChange is fired
    $("input[name='machinery']").change(function() {
        ifMachinery($(this));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/g63m9yyg/3/